# Why these 2 calls to same function?

Tags: node.js, express, ghost-blog

I'm looking at GhostJS source code for learning Nodejs. I didn't understand why these 2 calls with different params for the same function:

https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/688dd363cdf0084c20dd243b02c26afb6ebcabbe/core/server.js#L205-L206

Anyone could explain why that?

Thanks =D

EDIT:
This is the code at time of writing:

```
server.use('/ghost/upload/', express.multipart());
server.use('/ghost/upload/', express.multipart({uploadDir: __dirname + '/content/images'}));
```

EDIT 2 
See this github issue:
https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/issues/1511

Comment: Looks a bit useless to me.

Comment: Could you copy that code into your question?  If anyone checks in to that repository your link is going to be broken.

Comment: I actually implemented the switch to multipart on that route and while I can't tell you why it was necessary off the top of my head, I can tell you that without it being registered twice, uploads would simply fail. Probably something else going on there, just don't remember what it was off the top of my head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be traced back to the [first commit](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/c5fa7ae1a6b46d8f7266229ca815bbd2dd644ce4/core/server.js#L162-L163) for this file, where `bodyParser()` was used.

This adds two middlewares. The first `multipart` middleware will [flag the `body` as parsed](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/multipart.js#L98-L99) and do what it has to do:

```
req._body = true;
```

... and in the second run, the middleware won't do anything, as the [body is already parsed](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/multipart.js#L86):

```
return function multipart(req, res, next) {
    if (req._body) return next();
    ...
}
```

This looks like a mistake to me.